# Require "open-url" load error when executing Nokogiri tester

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to follow the RailsCast to use Nokogiri.

Just a few very basic lines in my testing script file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-url'

url = "http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_constraint=0&ic=48_0&search_query=Batman&Find.x=0&Find.y=0&Find=Find"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
```

But when I execute it, I run into an error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- open-url (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from nokogiri.test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I did install open url gem following this instruction:https://github.com/openurl/openurl
How do I fix the error message?

Comment: Ruby's [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) is built-in and is probably what you want to use. Try `require 'open-uri'` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just a typo. Use `open-uri` (not `open-url`).