# "require": cannot load such file-- open-url(LoadError)

Tags: rubygems, open-uri

Here's my .rb code. Kindly help please, thank you so much!

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_NBA_team_rosters"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri))

puts page
```

This is the error appear in my command prompt:

> C:\Sites>ruby wikipedia_scraper.rb
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- open-url (LoadError from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from wikipedia_scraper.rb:1:in `'

Comment: Hi @GhostCat : I'm so sorry, just starting to learn RO. It's my first time to post here. I have already edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Require "open-url" load error when executing Nokogiri tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488169/require-open-url-load-error-when-executing-nokogiri-tester)